# Loading MITab dll gives System.BadImageFormatException in c#

Tags: c#, c++, dll

This error has been frustrating me very badly, and I can't find anything on the web.

I have a MITab V1.7.0 dll and a MiApi.cs file that contains the following:

```
// $Id: MiApi.cs,v 1.2 2005/03/24 17:02:06 dmorissette Exp $
//

using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections;

namespace EBop.MapObjects.MapInfo {
  /// <summary>
  /// Wrapper functions for the version 1.3.0 of the MapInfo Tab API.
  /// </summary>
  /// <remarks>
  /// Requires MITab.dll (www.maptools.org)
  /// See http://mitab.maptools.org/
  /// 
  /// Graham Sims
  /// Environment Bay of Plenty, Whakatane, New Zealand
  /// http://www.envbop.govt.nz
  /// </remarks>
  public class MiApi {

    // -- enums left out for brevity //

    private MiApi() {
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the version of the library. 
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>An integer representing the current version of the MITAB library in the 
    /// format xxxyyyzzz, e.g. returns 1002004 for v1.2.4.  
    /// </returns>
    [DllImport("mitab.dll")]
    public static extern int mitab_c_getlibversion();

    // -- Other entry points -- //

  }
}
```

When I try to access it with;

```
int version = MiApi.mitab_c_getlibversion();
```

I get;

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.BadImageFormatException' occurred in BBX.IAP.MapInfoProcessor.exe

Additional information: An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B)
```

The standard response is that I am loading a 32bit library in a 64bit application or 64bit in 32bit, but I've recompiled in both, and recompiled the library as well. I've also checked the symbols and used cdb to examine the way the library is accessed, but I can't make much sense out of the output.

```
214c:2f54 @ -2131284890 - LdrLoadDll - ENTER: DLL name: C:\Users\Owen\X\deps\Debug\MITab.dll
214c:2f54 @ -2131284890 - LdrpLoadDll - ENTER: DLL name: C:\Users\Owen\X\deps\Debug\MITab.dll
214c:2f54 @ -2131284890 - LdrpLoadDll - INFO: Loading DLL C:\Users\Owen\X\deps\Debug\MITab.dll
214c:2f54 @ -2131284890 - LdrpFindOrMapDll - ENTER: DLL name: C:\Users\Owen\X\deps\Debug\MITab.dll
214c:2f54 @ -2131284890 - LdrpResolveDllName - ENTER: DLL name: C:\Users\Owen\X\deps\Debug\MITab.dll
214c:2f54 @ -2131284890 - LdrpResolveDllName - RETURN: Status: 0x00000000
214c:2f54 @ -2131284890 - LdrpMapViewOfSection - ENTER: DLL name: C:\Users\Owen\X\deps\Debug\MITab.dll
ModLoad: 00000000`1b680000 00000000`1b813000   C:\Users\Owen\X\deps\Debug\MITab.dll
214c:2f54 @ -2131284890 - LdrpMapViewOfSection - RETURN: Status: 0x4000000e
214c:2f54 @ -2131284890 - LdrpFindOrMapDll - RETURN: Status: 0xc000007b
214c:2f54 @ -2131284890 - LdrpLoadDll - RETURN: Status: 0xc000007b
214c:2f54 @ -2131284890 - LdrLoadDll - RETURN: Status: 0xc000007b
214c:2f54 @ -2131284890 - LdrLoadDll - ENTER: DLL name: MITab.dll
214c:2f54 @ -2131284890 - LdrpLoadDll - ENTER: DLL name: MITab.dll
214c:2f54 @ -2131284890 - LdrpLoadDll - INFO: Loading DLL MITab.dll
214c:2f54 @ -2131284890 - LdrpFindOrMapDll - ENTER: DLL name: MITab.dll
214c:2f54 @ -2131284890 - LdrpFindKnownDll - ENTER: DLL name: MITab.dll
214c:2f54 @ -2131284890 - LdrpFindKnownDll - RETURN: Status: 0xc0000135
214c:2f54 @ -2131284890 - LdrpSearchPath - ENTER: DLL name: MITab.dll
```

I've even confirmed that the symbol exists in the dll using dumpbin

```
1610  649 000015E1 _mitab_c_getlibversion@0 = @ILT+1500(_mitab_c_getlibversion@0)
```

The worst part is that I have output from the program that shows that it has worked successfully in the past. All I am left with is frustration and confusion.

Can anybody enlighten me as to what I have wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Okay...

Although I swore that I had made sure they were both x64... I was wrong.

MiTab.dll is an old library, and it was set as Win32. I had to go deeper into the compilation instructions to find where it was set to Win32 and change it. Immediately the error vanished.

Lesson: Even if all your settings say that the code is being generated as Win32 or x64, check it.